# Can I use an iPhone 4 micro-SIM card on Samsung Galaxy S?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s

I borrowed a Samsung Galaxy S device in order to test an app. I have attempted to insert my iPhone 4 sim card (micro-SIM) into the Galaxy S, yet the device won't recognize it and display a 'No SIM' error. Is the Galaxy S compatible with micro-SIM or do I need to purchase a different one?

Comment: look up your device specification on [GSMArena.com](http://www.gsmarena.com/results.php3?sQuickSearch=yes&sName=Galaxy+S) and check if it supports micro-sim or mini-sim.

Answer (score 1):

The Samsung Galaxy S (not S2; S3; S4 or S5) uses a mini-SIM. The iPhone 4 uses a micro-SIM. Maybe [Robert's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/85824/44325), well, kind of missed the wood for the trees.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, most of the SIM card mobile service providers have recently taken to heavy-handed self-protection tactics to retain their market share.

Most carriers have "tweaked" their SIM cards so you generally MUST purchase a SIM card that matches not only the service provider, but also the device configuration for which it was engineered.

While there might be a way to Flash a SIM card, but a new SIM card is so cheap it is not worth it.

Besides, SIM cards must be compatible with the device as well as the carrier.

For example, Simple Mobile is a subsidiary of T-Mobile and they both use SIM cards similar to Verizon's, however, none of these are "fully interoperable" with each other, as Verizon uses a different radio frequency for their LTE/4G or whatever thay are calling it now. 
Some SIM's from carrier "A" work on carrier "B" but not the other way around...

I am just waiting for a carrier that does not bother to collect my metadata.

If they didn't bother with all that overhead, our service would be dirt cheap...

Comment: Interesting, I've never heard of such a practice, at least here in Germany/Europe. The radio frequency is usually not related to the SIM card at all.